# Automorphisms and Galois Theory

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group

I have been given the polynomial $x^3-2$, I found the splitting field $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i\sqrt{3})$, then further deducing that $|G(E/\mathbb{Q})|=6$ and then that $G(E/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq S_3 \text{ or } C_6$. Further, by doing some calculations, I find that it is not commutative, thus $G(E/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq S_3$. However, I do not know how to find the order of these group elements, as I know by Lagrange's Theorem that the subgroups should consist of either one group of order 3 or three groups of order 2. My question is: how do I calculate this (the orders of these group elements)?

Comment: The Galois group will always be a permutation group that acts transitively on the roots of the polynomial (assuming that we have an irreducible polynomial).  Thinking about what the group elements does to the individual roots is often a productive way to think about the group.

Comment: There is no faithfully action of C6 on 3 elements..

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straightforward, actually.
Could you try to write down the definition of each element in your automorphism group?

---

Recall how you obtain those elements.$\newcommand{\rat}{\mathbb{Q}}$
First, any $\sigma\in G(E/\rat)$ is *completely determined* by its image on $2^{1/3}$ and $i\sqrt{3}$.
Also, $\sigma$ must map an element in $E$ to one of its conjugates over $\rat$.
Since there are $3$ conjugates of $2^{1/3}$ and $2$ conjugates of $i\sqrt{3}$ over $\rat$,
there are $6$ possibilities of an automorphism of $E$ fixing $\rat$.
We know that $|G(E/\rat)|=6$,
so all those $6$ possibilities induced by the conjugates maps
must be valid automorphisms.

To determine the order of, say, $\sigma\in G(E/\rat)$,
simply look at how its powers act on the elements $2^{1/3}$ and $i\sqrt{3}$ (see the second sentence of the last paragraph).
For example, if $\sigma$ is induced by $2^{1/3}\mapsto 2^{1/3}\exp(2\pi i/3)$
and $i\sqrt{3}\mapsto -i\sqrt{3}$,
then we can construct the following multiplication table
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 & \text{id} & \sigma & \sigma^2 \\
\hline
\sqrt[3]{2} & \sqrt[3]{2}  & \sqrt[3]{2}(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) & \sqrt[3]{2}\\
i\sqrt{3} & i\sqrt{3} & -i\sqrt{3} & i\sqrt{3}
\end{array}
$$
We see that $\sigma^2=\text{id}$ because they coincide on $2^{1/3}$ and $i\sqrt{3}$.
Then $\sigma$ has order $2$.
The calculation above is done as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sigma^2(\sqrt[3]{2}) &= \sigma(\sqrt[3]{2}(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})) \\
&= \sigma(\sqrt[3]{2})\sigma(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) \\
&= \sqrt[3]{2}(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) \sigma(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) \\
&= \sqrt[3]{2}(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma(i\sqrt{3}) )\\
&= \sqrt[3]{2}(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) (\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) \\
&= \sqrt[3]{2}.
\end{align*}
$$
In this case, the calculation is rather complicated.
If you use $E=\rat(\sqrt[3]{2},e^{2\pi i/3})$ for example,
then it would become much simpler.